# Creating a ticket in VMWare using PowerCLI when free storage in datastore is too less

Tags: vmware, vsphere, powercli

I am able to get the free space as ouptut by using the following code.

```
$body +=echo "------------Free space on Datastore.--------------"`r`n""`r`n""
$body +=get-datastore -name *datastore1* | sort Name | ForEach-Object {
    $output=New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
        Freespace = "$([math]::Round($_.FreeSpaceGB, 2)) GB"
        Datastore_Name = $_.Name
        }       
    }
    Write-Output $output
```

Is it possible to raise a ticket if the free space is less than 2 GB? If so, how should I change my code?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT :

```
if (get-datastore | where {$_.FreeSpaceGB -lt 2}){"dosomething"}
```

or

```
foreach ($ds in (get-datastore | where {$_.FreeSpaceGB -lt 2})){"dosomething"}
```

Comment: Please indent your code by 4 spaces to correctly format. Also it would be worth explaining what the code does.